# How to allocate memory to pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<string.h>

struct date {
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
};

struct person{
    char name[64];
    struct date birthday;
};

struct aop {
   int max;
   struct person **data;
};

 struct aop *create_aop(int max) {
    struct aop *new = malloc(sizeof(struct aop));
    new->data = malloc(max*sizeof(struct person));
    for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
    new->data[i] = NULL;
    }
    new->max = max;
    return new;}

void destroy_aop(struct aop *a) {
    free(a->data);
    free(a);
}


int add_person(struct aop *a, char *name, struct date birthday) {
    if (a->data[a->max-1] != NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    struct person *new_person = malloc(sizeof(struct person));
    strcpy(new_person->name, name);
    new_person->birthday = birthday;
    for (int i=0; i<a->max; i++) {
        if (a->data[i] == NULL) {
            a->data[i] = new_person;
            break;
        }
    }
    free(new_person);
    return 0;
}
```

I have some questions about the code I wrote. First, do I need to add extra codes into create_aop to initialize name and birthday inside of person? And I found that after the free(new_person) in add_person, I cannot reach a->data[0]->name. How can I change the of a->data[i] without using another pointer?

```
struct aop *birthdays(const struct aop *a, int month) {
    int m = a->max;
    struct aop *n = create_aop(m);
    int j = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
        if (a->data[i] != NULL) {
            if (a->data[i]->birthday.month == month) {
                n->data[j] = a->data[i];
                j++;
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (j == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Every time I run the function above, there are some errors memory. I have been thinking about it for hours but have no idea what is wrong in this one.

Comment: `new->data = malloc(max*sizeof(struct person));` --> `new->data = calloc(max, sizeof(struct person*));`, delete `free(new_person);`

Comment: Better `sizeof *new->data` than `sizeof(struct person*)`. Less error-prone.

Comment: In general, 'new' is a reserved word, Suggest using a better name.

Comment: I see zero reason for a pointer array in this code. From everything you asked in your question it at-least-appears that using one at all has done little besides confuse you. You allocation sizing is more inline with a single-indirection sequence anyway.

Comment: `destroy_aop` add `free(a->data[i])` each element of `a->data`.

Comment: the code, in add_person(), calls free(),  This should not be done until ready to delete a node.  Also, assigning one struct to another struct will not copy the struct.  suggest using memcpy()

Comment: It appears that you need to dynamically allocate only the `person**` array, not the `aop` structure (you can dynamically allocate both, but it's an overkill).

Comment: @user3629249 sure you cann assign one struct to another and it will be copied. just like you can assign an int (or any datatype) to another variable and the values will be copied. just think about when you call a function that expects a struct (*not* a pointer), then this function will have a *copy* of that struct. maybe you were confusing it with pointers.

Comment: Thank you all and I have figured out why it was wrong. But for the last function there are still some errors but I dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two big mistakes in this code. First, the allocation of your data array in struct aop is flawed.

```
new->data = malloc(max*sizeof(struct person));
```

You don't want it to point to memory of size max times length of a person struct, do you? Since it is a pointer to **pointers**, it's size only has to be max times length of a pointer, i.e.

```
new->data = malloc(max*sizeof(struct person*));
```

You could also let data directly point to struct person. Then the first line would be correct and you don't have to allocate memory each time you create a new person. Instead, you would just use the memory that data points to:

```
(aop->data[i]).name = ...
```

and so on.

Secondly, you are freeing your person struct right after creation.

```
free(new_person);
```

Now aop->data[i] is a dangling pointer, because the address it points to could be overwritten any time (because it's not locked by malloc anymore). Instead, you have to free it in your destroy function. It might look something like this:

```
void destroy_aop(struct aop *a) {    
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < a->max; i++)
    {
      if(a->data[i] != NULL) {
      free(a->data[i]);
      }
    }
    free(a->data);
    free(a);
}
```

Comment: I think this problem is solved. Here is another question, what is double-free? I run my main function and get this error.

Comment: this means that somewhere in your code, you're freeing a pointer that you've already called free() on before. for example if you copied my destroy function (which frees persons) but still left the call to free() in your add_person function - then you would get a double free when destroying.

Comment: Ok, but I don't think I free any pointer more than one time in my code, but there is an error says that attempting double-free. Is it because there are some other memory errors occur? And for my code of birthdays function, is there something wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: you have a potential memory leak in your birthday function. it allocates memory for an aop struct, but it is possible that you never return it (and thus don't free it). so, before `return NULL;` you have to call `free(n)`. not sure where the double free comes from though. also: what is this function supposed to do? if it should put *all* persons of the given month into the newly created aop, then you have to delete the `break;` statement in the else block.